# Avoid code duplication Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following `RestController` (Spring boot `2.0.4`)  with several methods that follow the same structure of `execute`. They may point out to different `url` or be annotated with `@GetMapping` instead of `@PostMapping`:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    private final DataAccessLayer dal;

    @PostMapping("myUrl_1") execute(@RequestBody String param) {

        try {
            ... 
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            ...
        } catch (CustomException_2 e_2) {
            ...
        } finally {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The only difference is the `param` usage and the `dal` usage.

My question is, **how can I avoid code duplication in `catch` and `finally` clauses??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler`.

`@ControllerAdvice` : By default `@ControllerAdvice` will apply to all classes that use the @Controller annotation. If you wanted this to be more specific then you can do so by writing some properties like `@ControllerAdvice("my.org.package")`

`@ExceptionHandler` : Using `@ControllerAdvice` along with `@ExceptionHandler` provides global error handling. You can write the annotations `@ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)` which will handle all the exception for `IllegalArgumentException`.

[For more details you can refer this :](https://www.journaldev.com/2651/spring-mvc-exception-handling-controlleradvice-exceptionhandler-handlerexceptionresolver)

Answer (score 0):

use `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler`. [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling)